# Got internal error 500 when sending email with Laravel 6 in production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I've never configured a Laravel mail settings before. **On development**, you know, **it works** but on production, I'm getting internal error 500.

In my mail controller, this is giving the error:

```php
[..]

Mail::to($toEmail)->send(new Support($support));
```

I've looked in `storage/logs/` and no logs are there. I now assume I'm missing a php module? My `.env`: `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`

Im using Ubuntu 18 with php 7.2 and nginx.

Also, why am I not seeing the log files?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried checking the usual log folder for your webserver, like `/var/log/apache2`, for error logs?

Comment: Apache? No. Im using Nginx. Nothing is in either access.log or error.log.

Comment: Additionally, what have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked all mail configuration? Is this happening on all recipient addresses? Does it work using other mail servers?

Comment: usually production logs in /var/logs/* check apache/nginx error logs and php too, you should include logs or at least a clear error message/

Comment: @NicoHaase I have not tried others. I shall do that now.

Comment: Have you tried setting your application to `dev` mode? Using Symfony, this prints all error messages instead of throwing a 500 error

Comment: Just tried with `smtp.googlemail.com` and same error. local dev can send email.

Comment: Though the mail commands were generated in a docker container but those files are in git.

Comment: Found this issue. Ive made changes to the `.env` file using `sudo` and that messed things up so I had to `chown -R www-data:www-data` the root dir. Thanks all!

Comment: What is the specific error shown in laravel's log?

Comment: No error. That was the pain point. It seems that the log folder was able to be written to.